# Css changing after ajax post

Tags: css

I have a list page which every row is like this.

```
<div class="column RightButtons">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" onclick="SetStudentPassword(2065)" value="Şifre Değiştir">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" onclick="OpenClassChangeDialog(2065)" value="Sınıf Değiştir">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" onclick="window.location.href = '/Parent/List?StudentId=2065'" value="Veliler">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" value="Düzenle" onclick="window.location.href = '/Student/Update?StudentId=2065'">
</div>
```

With ajax post I filter the rows and get new rows. I create a variable in javascript which contain html string like this.

```
<div class="column RightButtons">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" onclick="SetStudentPassword(2065)" value="Şifre Değiştir">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" onclick="OpenClassChangeDialog(2065)" value="Sınıf Değiştir">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" onclick="window.location.href = '/Parent/List?StudentId=2065'" value="Veliler">
<input type="button" class="btn Buttons" value="Düzenle" onclick="window.location.href = '/Student/Update?StudentId=2065'">
</div>
```

All attributes are same. All css are same. But the second html button are more closer than previous one. Please help

Comment: Maybe in one case there are no whitespace characters between the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably fighting inline-block and white-space.

You may try [several things](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) but the one I recommend, if you're buttons must remain inline-block, is to adjust the font size to zero.

```
.RightButtons {
    font-size: 0;
}
.RightButtons .btn {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Alternatively, if your buttons are to remain all on the same line you might try floating them left.

```
.RightButtons .btn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.RightButtons:after {
    content: ""
    display: table
    clear: both
}
```